# Hold phrasal verb for "waiting until something happens"

Tags: phrasal-verbs

I'm looking for the "hold" phrasal verb that means that I will stop doing something until something else is ready.

*"John's report is input to my task so I will wait for that*

Would that be? =>
*"John's report is input to my task so I will hold off/on/back for that*

Comment: What is it about your first quoted phrase that you find insufficient? I might say "required for my task" but what you have does seem to say just what you want.

Comment: 'Hold fire' is a metaphorical verbo-nominal MWV with that meaning.

Answer (score 1):

***hold off*** means:

> to not do something immediately:

> - They've decided ***to hold off*** on buying a car until they're both working. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hold-off))

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hold%20off) points out the transitive and intransitive uses of this phrasal verb.

> (transitive verb) to defer action on : ***POSTPONE***/to block from an objective : ***DELAY***
>
> - hold off a decision
>
> (intransitive verb) *to defer or temporarily stop doing something*

In your sentence

> John's report is input to my task so I will ***hold off*** for that.

***hold off*** is used intransitively with the meaning *I will not continue my task until John files in his report*.